# php DateTime add 1 week 12 times in a for loop

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I am making an attendance system, and when user selects a start date it will create 12 entries in the database  for weekId = 1 to 12 etc

But that's irrelevant really, the main thing is i want to know if there are better ways to increment the week output on the code below.

```
<?php
     $d=strtotime("today");
     echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d) . "<br>";
     for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
           $d=strtotime("+1 week", $d);
           echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $d) . "<br>";
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively inefficient to convert back and forth between a string and a date all the time. PHP includes a [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class that is designed for iterating dates.

You could use it like this:

```
$begin = new DateTime('2016-03-01');
$end = new DateTime('2016-03-01');
$end->modify('+12 weeks 1 day'); // Need an extra day. Last day not included.

// Period from begin to end, at 1 week intervals.
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1W'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Ymd") . "\n";
}
```

Comment: ahhh that's great didn't realise about DatePeriod that helps alot thanks for the annotations in the code :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is right. Simply, you can short it in this way:

```
for( $x = 0; $x < 12; $x++ )
{
    echo date( "Y-m-d h:i:sa", strtotime("today +{$x} week")) . "<br>\n";
}
```